# Download Artifacts from a Release Bundle in Jfrog

Tags: artifactory

When I create release bundles in Jfrog and then move them to a satellite, all artifacts on the satellite are placed in repositories from where I can download them. But they are stored there without reference to a specific release bundle. I can download any combination of artifacts. I am asking me if there is a possibility to download artifacts not from the repository but from the release bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that i would suggest to use the Jfrog CLI: 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI

Thats a tool developed in Jfrog itself for ease of use.
After you configure it (`jfrog config add`) you can use the following command to download all the files of a release bundle: 
`jfrog rt dl --bundle bundle_name/bundle_version`